# JavaScript array.every() method returns false when using the in operator?

Tags: javascript

Below is the `isSubSet()` function that checks if elements from subset B and subset C are in subset A are in the universal set.

```js
const isSubSet = (universalSet,subSet) => (
  subSet.every(element => element in universalSet)
)
const [setA,setB,setC ] = [ [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5]]
const [checkA, checkB ] = [,isSubSet(setA, setC)]

console.log(`is setB subset of setA: ${isSubSet(setA, setB)}`)
console.log(`is setC subset of setA: ${isSubSet(setA, setC)}`)
```

Does the array.every() return true for proper subsets only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

The [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) checks if a key of an object exists.

```js
const
    isSubSet = (universalSet, subSet) =>
        subSet.every(element => universalSet.includes(element));

const [setA, setB, setC] = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
const [checkA, checkB] = [, isSubSet(setA, setC)]

console.log(`is setB subset of setA: ${isSubSet(setA, setB)}`)
console.log(`is setC subset of setA: ${isSubSet(setA, setC)}`)
```